# Can't get WebClient.UploadFile from C# Rest service

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, upload

I'm currently trying to migrate some aspx pages into a C# Rest service.
I can't change the caller but only the called service.

Here is how I'm called:

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
// here I'm dealing with cookie but not sure it is worth explaining how I pass it cause it isn't the problem
var response = myWebClient.UploadFile(sURL, fileFulName); // fileFulName is the path of my local file
```

When in aspx, the file could be get this way:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];
```

First I tried the same with this code:

```
var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
```

Which throws an exception that I could manage by adding this into the web.config (appSettings section):

```
<add key="wcf:serviceHostingEnvironment:useClassicReadEntityBodyMode" value="true" />
```

But now, it throws no Exception but is an empty array.
Here is my endpoint method:

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "/upload?myParam={myGetParam}]
void Upload(Stream fileStream, string myGetParam);
```

I don't know how to do to get it working. I tried to use a byte array as input but the response was a 400 Bad Request. I then tried to see what is in the fileStream but it doesn't contains my file, only a few characters.

I have no idea on how I could get the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you create a route that you can upload files to in a .NET core REST API service:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(formFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                 // do something with the file content.
            }
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Saddly I don't have access to Microsoft.AspNetCore due to group policies. I look at a solution which doesn't use it. Currently I'm using System.ServiceModel namespace in my interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the code of my upload file function:

```
public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)

        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

            do

            {

                bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Service: Received file {0} with {1} bytes", fileName, totalBytesRead);

        }

 

The service contract:

 

   [ServiceContract] 

    public interface IReceiveData 

    { 

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")] 

        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents); 

    }

The main function:

 

static void Main(string[] args) 

        { 

            string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service"; 

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RawDataService), new Uri(baseAddress)); 

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IReceiveData), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior()); 

            host.Open(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Host opened"); 

  

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(baseAddress + "/UploadFile/Test.txt"); 

            req.Method = "POST"; 

            req.ContentType = "text/plain"; 

            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream(); 

            byte[] fileToSend = new byte[12345]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < fileToSend.Length; i++) 

            { 

                fileToSend[i] = (byte)('a' + (i % 26)); 

            } 

            reqStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length); 

            reqStream.Close(); 

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Client: Receive Response HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription); 

            host.Close(); 

  

        }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/create-a-service-arbitrary-data-using-wcf

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this code is that I can't change the call, only the called service. And with the calling call I provided, the Stream I receive doesn't contain the file. The size is 42 bytes as I uploaded a file which is over 1 ko.

Comment: Do you currently only have a WCF client and want to upload files to the server?

Comment: My client is a C# client (not WCF). The calling call is the one I added on my question. The problem is that I can do no change to the client calls. These calls were previously intercepted in aspx and worked fine, so I know the calling code isn't completely wrong even if not initially meant to call a REST service.